# Problem Installing My custom component that uses dll

Tags: delphi, dll, runtime, package, custom-component

I created a TCustomComponent and i am having problem on installing it. Error Message "????.dll  not found and cannot install package". but it work if you copy it to the system directory.

My question is, how to make my component installed like normal component without copying the .dll to the system directory or into the library.

i tried Adding the SearchPath and OPtions>Environment Variables and still not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The search path and options environment variables are for the *compiler,* not the IDE's loading.  The Delphi IDE loads the component packages and hosts them in its own memory space, so it follows the standard Windows rules on DLL loading.  You'll need to either put your DLL in the same folder as BDS.exe, or somewhere on the system search path.

Comment: You beat me!

Don't forget to mention you can modify the path environment variable to include the folder where you dll is located.  More info: [dll search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28VS.80%29.aspx)